# Cannot sync digital copy movie to iPad via itunes

Tags: itunes, ipad, data-synchronization, quicktime

I have two movies where I downloaded the digital copy (using the standard redemption method) to iTunes. They are mpeg-4 files, but unlike other mpeg-4 files, I cannot sync them to my iPad. It says, for example:

> "Paul (Unrated) [2011]" was not copied because the video format is not supported by the iPad "The Oracle".

If I try to double click and play it on my iMac, it says:

> This movie requires QuickTime, which is not supported by this version of iTunes.

I'm running iTunes 10.7. If I go to the actual file and double click it, I can view it with QuickTime.

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours with Apple Tech Support, we discovered that we needed to restart iTunes in 32-bit mode and then the movies would sync to my iPad and could be played in iTunes. To set 32-bit mode, Do a **Get Info** on the iTunes Application and check the "Open in 32-bit mode" checkbox.

Comment: This solution does nt works. Any alternate  solution for this.

Comment: Worked fine for me. Are you sure you have restarted iTunes in 32-bit mode? Does the movie play from iTunes on your Mac?

Comment: Actually few videos are getting player and few are not, what can be the reason for that?Like the videos on this link https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewCourse?id=497193807&s=143441&ls=1, i am unable to play any of the videos on this list.